Automated spline regression
As some CV members occasionally recommend spline regression, I wonder whether there is an automated algorithm for selecting the variables to which to apply splines, and the number of knots and their position. Something comparable to the CART algorithm for piecewise regression or random forests.
I have read the chapter in Frank Harrell's "Regression Modeling Strategies", which includes some rules of thumb and suggests the use of AIC to automatically select the number of knots, but I have the impression that it is meant for a procedure in which the statistician models his/her biases into the analysis. This is a valid approach, of course, but it seems to be feasible only for data with a handful of variables, either selected beforehand (due to the bias of some experts) or after some variable selection algorithm.
Is there some rigorous algorithm for spline regression and has someone compared it to CART or random forests?

This sounds like Algorithms for automatic model selection.

@user2974951 Yes, of course. This is the point of CART, LASSO, RF and many others. The question is, whether there is a worked out and tested method based on spline regression.

Generalized additive modeling technically can find ways of doing both. In terms of the optimal spline knot fit, you can fit each regression path with something like a thin plate regression spline and the model will automatically penalize how curvilinear that association is while doing this. Having said that, GAMs don't automatically justify ideal knot placement...there are other informal ways to check this within GAMs, but they're not really "automatic" so to speak.
In terms of selecting a subset of splines in a given model, packages like mgcv in R also achieve this by using the select = TRUE argument in the gam() function, which essentially applies a sort of quasi-regularization to the model by adjusting the penalization of the splines.

Apparently, the answer to my question is so well known that no one bothered to answer. Just in case someone else has the same question, here is a summary:
There is indeed an automated procedure for spline regression and it was elaborated already in 1991 by Friedman and called "Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines" (MARS). Although, in principle, it can be used with cubic splines, too, it is usually only implemented with linear splines, resulting in piecewise linear functions. Actually, it is a straightforward generalization of CART, which uses "zeroth order splines", i.e. constants and thus yields non continuous prediction functions.
The term "MARS" has been later trademarked and open source implementations of MARS therefore use other names, e.g. mda or earth.
I have found two application studies that compared CART and MARS, and MARS performed better than CART:

(1) Gutiérrez, Álvaro Gómez, Susanne Schnabel, and J. Francisco Lavado Contador. "Using and comparing two nonparametric methods (CART and MARS) to model the potential distribution of gullies." Ecological modelling 220.24 (2009): 3630-3637.
(2) Mathapo, Madumetja Cyril, et al. "Comparison of MARS, CART, and Linear Regression Models for Prediction of Body Weight of Non-descript Indigenous Goats in Lepelle-Nkumbi Local Municipality, South Africa." (2024).

Beware that the abstract of (2) claims the opposite (i.e. CART performs better), but from Table 2 it is clear that this allegation in the abstract was based on the in sample error, whereas with respect to the out of sample error, MARS performs better. This shows that CART overfits the data, whereas MARS generalizes better to out-of-sample data.

MARS can have some overfitting problems.  RMS also provides a strategy that is more unbiased, based on giving more knots to variables that are not known to act linear and that are “more promising” using a blinded index of predictive potential.

Although some effects might be prescribed by prior knowledge, I doubt that there are many situations where you can be certain that a variable interacts strictly linear with the response. Usually, only a monotone relationship might be plausible, which would still require a piecewise approach. In any case, the rules of thumb in your book seem to be for hand-crafted models. Or did you formalize them into an "objective" algorithm for model construction?

Not fully objective, more of a way of spending degrees of freedom, i.e., specifying # parameters per predictor in descending order by the predictive potential (either from subject matter knowledge or empirical).  Based on the idea that steep relationships are dangerous to underfit.
